# Substitute for Onion Powder

Tags: substitutions, onions, seasoning, american-cuisine

I live in Europe but use many US recipes. These often call for onion powder which is hard to find here. Diced or minced onion is often not a good alternative and whilst garlic powder is easier to obtain, I find it complements rather than replaces onion powder. What could I use as (an easy to obtain) substitute for onion powder?

Comment: It won't work if the recipe actually *needs* onion powder (because it's dry and concentrated) but if it's just for lazy seasoning you could just saute some finely minced onion and get it thoroughly browned.

Comment: I'm in the UK. I never see onion powder in the shops, but it's not hard to find on the internet. Google is your friend...

Comment: In the UK Tesco sell it. Also the Asian markets usually stock it.

Comment: Thanks for the Asian market suggestion - I will try my local one

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/what-can-i-substitute-for-onions and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/substitute-for-onions-and-garlic

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you could make your own [onion powder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89W6_rCmtRQ). It isn't that difficult.

> 1. Peel and finely chop your onions.
> 2. Then, spread the onion pieces out on a tray and heat in a 150°F degree oven or in a food dehydrator until dry.
>
> Tip: The onions are dry when you can easily crumble the chopped pieces
>   in your hand.
>
> 3. Allow the onions to cool. Then, grind with a coffee grinder, spice mill, food processor or mortar and pestle until you reach your desired
>      consistency.
> 4. Store your finished onion powder in an air-tight container in a cool, dry spot or freeze.

Comment: Oven temperature of 150 °C or °F?

Comment: 150°F - clarified in the answer as well, thanks.